# Magento2: I need to change the position of custom mass action dropdown option in sales order grid

Tags: magento2

I need to change the position of custom mass action dropdown option in sales order grid

Please check screenshot:

[image]

Just need to show the Sync option to on top position before delete.

Does anyone have idea for the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is working for a sales order grid. But how I can show the same option on top in customer listing dropdown mass action?

Comment: please reply for above question

Comment: I thought both are same as both are mass Action Dropdown can you share a few more detail ScreenShot - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a plugin:

adminhtml/di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction">
        <plugin name="CustomVendor_CustomActions::sort_actions" type="CustomVendor\CustomActions\Plugin\Component\MassAction" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin\Component\MassAction.php:

```
<?php

namespace CustomVendor\CustomAction\Plugin\Component;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class MassAction
{

    /** @var RequestInterface */
    private $_request;

    /**
     * MassAction constructor.
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface  $request
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param ComponentMassAction $massAction
     */
    public function afterPrepare(ComponentMassAction $massAction)
    {
        if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() === 'sales_order_index') {

            $config = $massAction->getData('config');

            if (isset($config['actions']) && $config['actions']) {

                $count = 0;

                foreach (["custom_action_1" => 0, "custom_action_2" => 1] as $actionType => $position) {

                    /** @var $config mixed[][] */
                    foreach ($config['actions'] as $key => $action) {

                        if ($action['type'] == $actionType) {
                            $newPosition = max((int) $position, $count);
                            $this->moveElement($config['actions'], $key, $newPosition);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    $count++;
                }

                $massAction->setData('config', $config);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $actions
     * @param int $oldPosition
     * @param int $newPosition
     */
    public function moveElement(&$actions, $oldPosition, $newPosition)
    {
        $outputArray = array_splice($actions, $oldPosition, 1);
        array_splice($actions, $newPosition, 0, $outputArray);
    }

}
```

I had no luck using module sequence or sortOrder param in XML to achieve this. Plugin is the only method that worked for me in Magento 2.4.3.